# How does the flag "-mpreferred-stack-boundary=3" work?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, memory-alignment, stack-memory

I was compiling the below code with GCC and the flag "-mpreferred-stack-boundary=3". Here I want to know why there is a `and rsp, -16` in the generated ASM code? And how does this flag affect the stack alignment?

**C Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int arr[][3] = {
      {1,2,3},{3,4,5}
    };
    printf("%d", **(arr+1));
    printf("%d", *(*arr+2));
}
```

**ASM Code**:

```
.LC0:
        .string "%d"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        and     rsp, -16   # <-
        sub     rsp, 32
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp], 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+4], 2
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+8], 3
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 3
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+16], 4
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+20], 5
        mov     rax, rsp
        add     rax, 12
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     rax, rsp
        add     rax, 8
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

Comment: `-16` is `0xf...f0` or `~15` (two's complement to 16). I would have expected `-8` (`0xf...f8`) or `~7` for an eight bytes boundary, but there must be a subtlety...

Comment: Apparently `-mno-sse` makes it go away.  [This bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53383) seems relevant but I didn't sort through the explanation.

Comment: `-O` makes it go away too.  A guess would be that without optimization, gcc uses a standard function prologue that allows for the possibility of the function using SSE later, which would make 16-byte alignment necessary.  With optimization, the compiler recognizes that the function doesn't actually do that, so the unnecessary alignment is skipped.

Comment: Note that using `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=3` when calling library functions is likely to crash, since the library probably expects 16-byte alignment and may use SSE instructions that require it (scanf is notorious for this, and maybe printf too).  Unless you also recompiled your C library with `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=3`.